# State Persistence and Background Jobs

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to develop a tally counter app with React Native and Redux where:

- The user can create counters, give them a name and choose a frequency at which they will be reset (every day, week, month, year, ever);
- Counter increments are saved as dates and persisted, even when a counter is reset (so I can display statistics such as: over the last month, n *things* were counted, which is 10% more than the previous month).

I guess the state of a counter might look like this:

```
{
  name: 'Coffees',
  items: [
    'MM/DD/YYYY',
    'MM/DD/YYYY',
    'MM/DD/YYYY',
    'MM/DD/YYYY
  ]
}
```

And I could have an `INCREASE_COUNTER` action (which inserts a new date into the `items` array) and a `RESET_COUNTER` (which empties the `items` array).
But in this case, how:

1. Would you automatically reset this state (ideally even when the app is closed) at the frequency chosen by the user;
2. Would you persist past states (when a counter is reset) and get them back when necessary.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You could look into AsyncStorage (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) for storing your past states. And I dont know about executing things when the app is closed but you could always do what you need to do with a check each time the user launches the app ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I'll look into AsyncStorage.